# Spring redirect url issue when behind Zuul proxy

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I've been trying to get to the bottom of a strange redirection issue for the past 2 days without success.

Based on the spring-cloud example projects, I've configured Eureka, Zuul and a basic service that runs behind Zuul.

I have the following method;

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register")
public String registerDevice(Principal principal, String response) {
  // ...
  return "redirect:/account";
}
```

The form is setup to post to the proxied URL as follows;

```
POST https://localhost:8443/service/register
```

(Zuul is running on localhost:8443).

The URL for the local service (non-proxied) would be; http://localhost:9001/register

The POST call is proxied correctly through to the above method, however the redirect location sent to the browser is the non-proxied URL of the service; http://localhost:9001/account

The Zuul proxy is definitely sending the correct **x-forwarded-*** headers, so I would expect the view resolver in Spring to build the correct redirect based on the x-forwarded values.

To prove the headers are sent correctly, I reconfigured the method as follows;

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/register")
public void registerDevice(Principal, String response, HttpServletResponse response) {
  // ...
  String rUrl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/account").build().toUriString();
  servletResponse.sendRedirect(rUrl);
}
```

Which correctly redirects the browser to the proxied location; https://localhost:8443/service/account

Is this a bug, or is it expected behaviour? I thought using "redirect:" was meant to honour the forward headers passed from a proxy.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see [`RedirectView`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.0.RC1/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.java#L301-L320) ignores `X-FORWARDED-*` headers.
Simply put, you can't use "`redirect:/account"`.

Instead instantiate a `RedirectView` and configure it accordingly:

```
RedirectView redirect = new RedirectView("account");
redirect.setHosts(new String[]{ request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-HOST") });
```

Since Spring Framework 4.3 (currently RC1) [`setHosts`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.0.RC1/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.java#L267) method is available.

Comment: I have the same issue and don't see setHosts() in latest version of RedirectView (v4.2.5)

Comment: @damien-polegato you are right! `setHosts` method has been added in Spring Framework 4.3. I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, my question with same issue here if you have any clue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881835/spring-mvc-web-app-behind-zuul-redirect-issue

Answer (score 2):

If you are using tomcat as embeded server in your backend app, you could use this settings (application.properties, yml, etc):

```
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

Or more generic way:

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
```